# What does this means 程度は知ったほうが良い when someone gave other person an advice?

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english, conversations

**程度は知ったほうが良い
Hope someone can explains this expression's meaning.**

**Context: 2 subordinates saw their general went too far ahead from his troops in a battle. Although this general is strong and killed many enemies just by himself, his 2 subordinates said he's too hasty/ impatient and they also gave this general their honest advices.**

孫堅 (The General)「ははは、程普！　手柄を持っていかれて悔しいのはお前のほうだろう？」

からかうように孫堅が笑うと、苦言を呈するように韓当が言った。

韓当(Subordinate 1)「いいえ、私から見ても孫堅様はやりすぎです。はりきるのは分かりますが、後方の兵たちがまったくついて来れていません」

孫堅「それを言われると言葉がないな。
何しろ、娘がせっかちなのも俺のせいにされているほどだからな」

**程普(Subordinate 2)「まあ、程度は知ったほうが良いでしょうな。
御覧なさい。もう何も残ってはおりませんぞ」**

Answer (score 3):

程度は知ったほうが良い　simply means literally "It's better to know how far you're going!" Or if you wanna paraphrase it and contextualize it, "you're going too far!"

程度 means progress/depth, and here it's just "how far (one) is going."

XXしたほうがいい is common expression, and means "it's better to do XX" or "Should do XX". It's what people use to give advice. Note how the verb is in past tense, but the meaning conveyed is not in past tense.

Breaking the ほうがいい part down, we know that ほう・方 is indicating choice, and literally means "the side", so 知った方 means "the side of knowing" が is the subject-particle, いい is good. Together, 知ったほうがいい is literally "The side/choice of knowing is good", or, "You should know."